# code generation with xtend without removing the previous generated code

Tags: eclipse, code-generation, dsl, xtext, xtend

I am using xtend to generate java code,i am generating something like this:

`public class A {
     public void service ( ) {
       // this section is reserved to be implemented by the developper
     }`

My problem is that every time i update my dsl file  after saving, eclipse regenerate java code and remove the code written inside the methode 'service', is there any solution to make eclipse change only the updated part in the generated code ?

Comment: did you consider generation gap pattern or reviving https://github.com/danieldietrich/xtext-protected-regions or reading the file on generation (IFileSystemAccessExtension*1-4) has methods for that

Comment: i am using this to generate java file         fsa.generateFile("FunctionalSystem" + ".java", generateFunctionalSystem)

Comment: As I said. You need to consider alternate ways doing this